# How to fetch Token data from uniswapV3?

Tags: web3js, tokens, ethereumjs, uniswapv3, subgraph

I am trying to fetch some token data from uniswapV3 subgraph.

https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v3

> token address is: **0x06450dEe7FD2Fb8E39061434BAbCFC05599a6Fb8**

i can view details prices , transactions on etherscan on this link.
https://etherscan.io/dex/uniswapv3/0x2a9d2ba41aba912316d16742f259412b681898db.

i apply the query in subgraph

```
{
tokenDayDatas(
  where: {
    token: "0x06450dEe7FD2Fb8E39061434BAbCFC05599a6Fb8",
    date_gt: 15617173
  }, 
  orderBy: date, 
  orderDirection: asc) {
date
token {
  id
  symbol
}
untrackedVolumeUSD,
priceUSD,
}
}
```

But i am not able to fetch any data. How i can fetch this data from subgraph / from any other source to my frontend

Answer (score 0):

In The Graph, all tokens need to be lower case

it works in lower case

[image]